# How to subtract a DateTime by a changing time

Tags: php, datetime

I've seen various posts asking how to subtract a specific number of hours, days, etc from a DateTime - but my question is a bit different.

Say I have a user log in, and the system records the date/time. Every second, a timer increases based on the difference between the current date/time and the recorded date/time - effectively creating a log-in timer. Then, the user decides to pause the timer, so the system records pause start and pause end (for when they resume). What I would like to do is make the displayed time subtracted by the pause time - such that the timer doesn't 'increase' while paused. Because I'm not using an actual counter adding up every second, in which case I could just not count up during lunch, I am unaware how to calculate the proper value on the timer.

Here is the code on displaying the timer (part of incriment.php):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$date = new DateTime(date('m/d/Y H:i'));
$date2 = new DateTime(date($_SESSION['date_in'] . ' ' . 
$_SESSION['time_in']));
$interval = $date->diff($date2);
$interval = $interval->format('%H:%I');
$_SESSION['current_timer'] = $interval;
echo $_SESSION['current_timer'];
```

And here is the code on being paused

```
if(isset($_SESSION['paused']) && $_SESSION['paused'] === true) {
    echo '<div class="info">';
    echo '<img src="images/information-button" style="max-width:3em">';
    if(isset($_SESSION['pause_start'])) {           
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
        if(isset($_SESSION['pause_end'])) {
            $time = $_SESSION['pause_end']->diff($_SESSION['pause_start']);
            echo '<br>Current pause time: ' . $time->format('%H:%I'); 
        } else {
            $time = new DateTime(date('H:i'));
            $time = $time->diff(new DateTime($_SESSION['date_pause_start'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['pause_start']));
            $_SESSION['pause_timer'] = $time->format('%h hours, %i minutes');
            echo '<br>Pause timer: ' . $time->format('%h hours, %i minutes');
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

TLDR; How can I subtract a DateTime by an object returned by diff when I don't know if that diff will return minutes (say 30 minutes) or hours (say 1 hour, 30 minutes). I can't do [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_date_sub) as a result of not knowing that, nor can I do something like `$date->modify("+30 minutes")` because I don't know if it's minutes or hours or what. I feel like it should be easy because in my lunch calculations, `$time` is displaying the time paused (ex: 30 minutes) and by using that into a string I could use the`$date->modify` strategy - but that's not working (See below what I tried in my incriment.php I showed earlier)

```
$interval = $interval->format('H:i');
if(isset($_SESSION['pause_timer'])) {
    $interval = new DateTime(date($interval));
    $interval = $interval->modify("-". $_SESSION['pause_timer']);
    echo '-' . $_SESSION['pause_timer'];
}
```

But that echo's out -0 hours, 40 minutes if the user was paused for 40 minutes - and changes the time from 01:48 to 14:18 which is really confusing as it should be 1:08 obviously. That means to me that I'm improperly using the DateTime for my situation, is there a better solution

Thank you!

Edit: The user can only pause once per session for simplicities sake

Comment: I think getTimestamp is your friend here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php . Once a timestamp, you can just do simple subtraction or addition of seconds, and then format it as needed.

Comment: Timestamp may also do it. If I had my time at 08:20 and my lunch was at 00:30 - and I subtracted 08:20 by 00:30, would it be 7:50 or would it think 00:30 is military time for 12:30 am and thus it would subtract 8:20 am by 12:30am? If that wouldn't work, would it work if i had it formatted 0 hours, 30 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the replies in comments [even those they deleted ;) ], I managed to get it working by changing the paused code at the  `$_SESSION['pause_timer'] = $time->format('%h hours, %i minutes')` into   `$_SESSION['pause_timer'] = $time->format('-%h hours, -%i minutes')`. My problem was that I was subtracting only the hours, so when my time was only in minutes it added the minutes and subtracted the 0 hours!

Comment: If you're worried about how PHP will know what time is what, then use createFromFormat: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php